# How to check whether the image is a corrupted image?

Tags: image-processing, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a model with python to classify images. The dataset I want to use contains grayscale images, and includes corrupted images such as these:

[image]

[image]

**Note that this image has a lot of black pixels on the left side but a lot of bright pixels on the right side(relatively to the images shown at the bottom):**

[image]

While other images can also contain a lot of black pixels but are not corrupted:

[image]

I have tried to count the number of black pixels and remove images that have more than 2000 black pixels, but realized that I also find images that are not corrupted.

```
if np.count_nonzero(images[i]==0) > 2000:
    corrupted_indexes.append(i)
```

How can I find only corrupted images?

Note that there are also corrupted images with crops that are only a quarter of the image and images with thinner black lines that can also hurt the training of the model I think.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is compute the average black value of each image and if the value of an incoming image is greater than that average consider it corrupt.

Comment: The problem is that there are some corrupted images that contain a lot of bright pixels, I have edited the question so you can see an example. And there are corrupted images with pretty thin black lines so I rather consider them corrupted too.

Comment: You probably solved this already, but try it out, the avg black value from the examples you posted make it seem like a non-corrupted image will have less 0x000000 in it.

Comment: Wow this was long time ago but I think the final solution was to filter all the images that had like a couple of rows or columns with black pixels.Anyways from my knowledge today, I think removing images with many black pixels would remove most corrupted images and a small amount of non-corrupted so it would be fine(if the dataset is large enough).